# libgccjit problems when building gccEmacs from source

Tags: gcc, emacs

When I tried to build version `30.0.50` of `GNU Emacs` from source, I got stuck at the configure stage. There occurs an error, related to `libgccjit`. The error message is shown below:

> configure: error: The installed libgccjit failed to compile and run a
> test program using the libgccjit library.

I have installed `gcc12` through `Macports`, and someone told me that the `libgccjit` had been contained in `gcc12` since `gcc10`. So according to this account the building procedure should go well, but now it goes wrong. I don't know what the problem is. Any hints or suggetions are greatly appreciated.

I tried to install and compile the `libgccjit` from source, but I don't know how to do that, and I'm now still in a daze.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other, please.